# How to nest tab in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to nest tab view as a child of column in flutter?

I don't want to add tabs as a child of app bar `bottom` cause my tabs are not on top. It is somewhere in the body.

So I tried the above method & also I tried wrapping it inside a nested scaffold. Both of them seems not working.

Following is what I've tried.

```
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: TextInput(
                placeholder: 'Search',
                leadingIcon: searchIcon,
              ),
            ),
            DefaultTabController(
              length: 3,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - How to make a custom TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314082/flutter-how-to-make-a-custom-tabbar)

Comment: I don't want to use the tabs as bottom of app bar. I want custom.

Comment: where can you see the navbar being shown on the bottom from the link I shared?

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to extract it in to a separate widget. When I try separating it I'm getting error.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What error you're getting?

Comment: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
```RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout.```
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column ```RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.```. There is a lot! when I wrap it in a separate widget.

Comment: Can you please show the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I want to wrap it in to a separate widget and use it as child of another column!

Comment: Ok. Thank you all. I've it working now.

Comment: Is it possible to make the tabs sticky on top on scroll?

Comment: Yes, but it'll need work around and a little complex solution

Comment: How can I work it out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68341788/how-to-solve-overflow-issues-in-flutter-tabs

Comment: Let me see ...

Answer (score 1):

give a height to tabcontroller and then wrap tabbarview with expanded.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
              height:10,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ),
            Container(
              height:100,//add height as per your need
              child:DefaultTabController(
              length: 3,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child:TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                    ],
                  ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ),
            ])))
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I've it working now. Great!

Comment: Is it possible to make the tabs sticky on top on scroll?

Comment: You mean you want the tab bar to remain on top and the view to be scrollable?

Comment: Yea.  When I scroll up I want the tab to sticky below the app. bar. (like position: sticky in html css)

Comment: Can you try solving this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68341788/how-to-solve-overflow-issues-in-flutter-tabs

Comment: Okay hold on will check it