# How to solve overflow issues in flutter tabs?

Tags: flutter

Following is a custom tab I've created:

```
class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final tabs;
  final views;

  Tabs({this.tabs, this.views});

  @override
  _TabsState createState() => _TabsState();
}

class _TabsState extends State<Tabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: widget.tabs.length, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Container(
        height: size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 45,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom:
                      BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 3),
                ),
              ),
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                controller: _tabController,
                indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: -2.5),
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    width: 4,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                labelColor: Colors.blue,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                tabs: [
                  ...widget.tabs.map(
                    (e) => Tab(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          e,
                          style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [...widget.views],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But as soon as I use it inside my app screen, I'm getting overflow issues:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: "Home"
        elevation: 0,
        toolbarHeight: 36,
      ),
      drawer: DrawerNavigation(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Tabs(
              tabs: ['tab1', 'tab2'],
              views: [
                Tab1(),
                Tab2(),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting from is from single child scroll view.

I've tried removing single child scroll view from the tabs, but then the custom tabs wont' work.

Answer (score 0):

just remove single child scroll view from custom Tab like this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final tabs;
  final views;

  Tabs({this.tabs, this.views});

  @override
  _TabsState createState() => _TabsState();
}

class _TabsState extends State<Tabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: widget.tabs.length, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      height: size.height,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 45,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 3),
              ),
            ),
            child: TabBar(
              isScrollable: true,
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: -2.5),
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 4,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              labelColor: Colors.blue,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              tabs: [
                ...widget.tabs.map(
                  (e) => Tab(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        e,
                        style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [...widget.views],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and convert stateless widget (Home) into stateful widget and it will work fine like this,

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Tabs(
              tabs: ["tab1", "tab2"],
              views: [okay(), okay()],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But I'm still getting overflow errors, when the ```okay()``` tab contains elements that takes ups space. Also the overflow issue increases on screen rotation.

Comment: Cause inside ```okay()``` tab there needs to be list since I've a list of elements inside these tabs.

Comment: have to tried wrapping list with `SingleChildScrollView()` or You are using `ListView.Builder()` then enable `shrinkwrap` to true