# How to do flutter action button?

Tags: flutter, function, user-interface, uibutton, flutter-layout

Hi i created a flutter application in that i'm using tab-controller for multi screens and then i'm keeping one scaffold for screen. in that scaffold one action button is placed. now i want to use that action button for both screens.[this is image for my application click and view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUEz5.png)

please provide a solution to use the action button. advance thanks.

````
  const BloodRequestHome({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BloodRequestHomeState createState() => _BloodRequestHomeState();
}

class _BloodRequestHomeState extends State<BloodRequestHome> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final pages = [
    const RequestList(),
    const MyRequest(),
  ];

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: FlutterColor.BACGROUND_COLOR,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: FlutterColor.BLOODAPPBAR,
          title: const Text(
            "Blood Request",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          actions: [
            _selectedIndex == 1
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.filter_list_rounded,
                          size: 25.0,
                        )),
                  )
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
        body: pages[_selectedIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: custom(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container custom(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: FlutterColor.WHITE_COLOR,
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: FlutterColor.BOTTOMNAVSHAW, //New
                blurRadius: 5.0,
                offset: const Offset(0, -3))
          ],
          color: FlutterColor.WHITE_COLOR,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 05.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15, vertical: 10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: _selectedIndex == 0
                        ? FlutterColor.BOTTOMNAVCON
                        : FlutterColor.WHITE_COLOR,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/request_list.png',
                        scale: 20.0,
                        color: _selectedIndex == 0
                            ? FlutterColor.BOTTOMNAVTEXT
                            : FlutterColor.BLACK_COLOR,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Request List",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            color: _selectedIndex == 0
                                ? FlutterColor.BOTTOMNAVTEXT
                                : FlutterColor.BLACK_COLOR),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            const VerticalDivider(
              thickness: 2,
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0, left: 5.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15, vertical: 10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: _selectedIndex == 1
                          ? FlutterColor.BOTTOMNAVCON
                          : FlutterColor.WHITE_COLOR,
                      borderRadius:
                          const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/my_request.png',
                        scale: 21.0,
                        color: _selectedIndex == 1
                            ? FlutterColor.BOTTOMNAVTEXT
                            : FlutterColor.BLACK_COLOR,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "My Request",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            color: _selectedIndex == 1
                                ? FlutterColor.BOTTOMNAVTEXT
                                : FlutterColor.BLACK_COLOR),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}``` this is my code for your reference
````

Comment: Can you please add some code, so that we can know what solution can be provided.

Comment: do u want to create a reusable button?

Comment: i attached my code for your refernce

Comment: I just already answered check that also, it may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69356048/11789675

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your button click

```
   void goToPreviousPage() {
        _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index - 1);
      }

 void goToNextPage() {
        _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index + 1);
      }
```

Comment: No this is not my answer. please again red the quest with my updated