# How to set TabBarView without appbar height automatically

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make tabbar without appbar, it's done but one thing is messed up, it's the height of TabBarView i want the height follow with the tabs content but it result error. I already try using Expanded but not working evrything just gone.

if you have free time please help :) i put my full code in my repo
https://github.com/ccprogrammer/movies-app

here the image

[image]

here is my build code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Const.colorPrimary,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          _buildHeaders(),
          _buildTitle(),
          _buildTabBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

here is my tabbar code

```
Widget _buildTabBar() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 48.h,
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.w, 50.h, 18.w, 0),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4.w, 4.h, 4.w, 4.h),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Const.colorIndicatorBorder),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.r),
          ),
          child: TabBar(
            controller: _tabBarController,
            indicator: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: StadiumBorder(),
              color: Const.colorIndicator,
            ),
            labelStyle: Const.textPrimary.copyWith(fontSize: 14.sp),
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Detail'),
              Tab(text: 'Reviews'),
              Tab(text: 'Showtime'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.4,
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabBarController,
            children: [
              DetailsTab(),
              DetailsTab(),
              DetailsTab(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

here is the tabs code

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 32.h, 0, 0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          _buildSynopsis(),
          _buildCast(),
          _buildPhotos(),
          _buildVideos(),
          _buildBlogs(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best Way i Found for implemt Tabbar. I always flow this and implement it more then 10 applications.

[checkout this solution from stackover flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314082/flutter-how-to-make-a-custom-tabbar)

Comment: does the tabbarview works well inside of list view?

Comment: Yes absolutely it's working correctly. You just need to take care of scrolling physics 

somewhere you have to assign

 physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), if listview inside signlechildscroll view or similar

Answer (score 0):

You can set `height` parameter in `Tab` widget:

```
Tab(text: 'Detail', height: 150,),
```

- update:
  This is my custom `tabBar` widget:

  ```
  class AppTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Object> pages;
  final List<Tab> myTabs;

  const AppTabbedPage({Key? key, required this.pages, required this.myTabs})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppTabbedPageState createState() => _AppTabbedPageState();
  }

    class _AppTabbedPageState extends State<AppTabbedPage>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: widget.myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: TabBar(
            labelStyle: AppStyles.subTitle16Style,
            isScrollable: true,
            labelColor: AppColors.darkBlue,
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: widget.myTabs,
            unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.darkGrey,
            indicatorColor: AppColors.darkBlue,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: widget.pages.map((page) {
              return page as Widget;
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  }
  ```

Comment: but i dont want to specify the height, i want the height follow with the tabs content but it result error

Comment: :'( already try that wraping tabbar with expanded but it result empty screen

Comment: I’m using this class without any problems!!

Comment: okay i will try rewrite the enitre code, but does your tabbar wrapped inside list view ? because mine is