# How to Move This TabBar Position from Upper to Middle One in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar

I was trying to move the TabBar based on picture below. I wanted to move its position right under the piano picture in the middle. I am confused of which place should I put the TabBar. Here is my complete codes:

```js
class MusicAmbient extends StatefulWidget {
  const MusicAmbient({super.key});

  @override
  State<MusicAmbient> createState() => _MusicAmbientState();
}

class _MusicAmbientState extends State<MusicAmbient> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: const [
            Tab(text: "Epic"),
            Tab(text: "Relax"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: const Color.fromARGB(115, 55, 55, 55),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                //Piano Background & Tabs
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Wrap(
                    children: [
                      ImageButton(path: bgamb, callback: () => Get.back(), type: IconType.NONE),
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        color: const Color.fromARGB(115, 55, 55, 55),
                        child: TabBarView(
                          controller: controller,
                          children: [
                            MusicEpic(),
                            MusicRelax(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve it correctly in Flutter? Any tips and tricks will be appreciated.  [image: Desire Layout]

[image: Default Layout]

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to get

Comment: Wait. I will upload the image. Done

Comment: ohh it's to much simple [chekout this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319363/13078639)